# CSS - Input at 100% width overlaps div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fix a regular input box with padding, border, inside a div with padding. However, I want the input to have its width to be 100% but as you can see, it overlaps. How do I fix this?

CSS

```
#one {
    background:red;
    width:300px;
    padding:5px;
}
#two {
    width:100%;
    border:3px solid blue;
    padding:4px;
}
```

​

HTML

```
<div id="one"><input type="text" value="Test" id="two" /></div>​
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Add `box-sizing: border-box` to the `input` styles. Otherwise, the width is `100%`, PLUS the border and padding.

Comment: The `-moz-` prefix is required in Firefox, as of version 15 Aurora: http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing

Comment: @Web_Designer Seriously, they still haven't removed the prefix? Wow... Well, I already use a class for box-sizing that includes prefixes, so I don't need to worry :3