# The input with 100% width inside a div is overlapping the div

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with margin in the input with width 100%, because it is overlapping the div container.

I looked for solutions on the forum, and the possible solution was to apply box-sizing: border-box, but it is not working.

Solution not working to me: [CSS - Input at 100% width overlaps div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059628/css-input-at-100-width-overlaps-div)

```
jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/igorac1999/fuovpkba/
```

```css
html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body, pre {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container_calculator {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: tomato;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px auto;
}

.container_calculator > label {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px 0 0 20px;
}

.container_calculator > input {
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px 20px;
}


div.result_bin2dec {
  border: 1px solid #edf2f7;
  background-color: #edf2f7;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 35px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container_calculator">
            <label>Number</label>
            <input type="text" id="number">
        </div>

        <div class="result_bin2dec">
            <pre>
                Dec: 10
                Bin: 01
            </pre>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jESNu.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead `margin` on the children, you may use `padding` on the parent , so it can be included in `box-sizing`

---

*as specified in the linked answer you said did not work for you , see below the link to specification of box-sizing to understand how it works and how to use it*

---

possible example: https://jsfiddle.net/gr7cbevj/

```css
html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body,
pre {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container_calculator {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: tomato;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  padding: 0 20px;/* added */
  box-sizing: border-box;/* added */
}

.container_calculator>label {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0px;/* modified */
}

.container_calculator>input {
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px 0px;/* modified */
}

div.result_bin2dec {
  border: 1px solid #edf2f7;
  background-color: #edf2f7;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container_calculator">
    <label>Number</label>
    <input type="text" id="number">
  </div>

  <div class="result_bin2dec">
    <pre>
                Dec: 10
                Bin: 01
            </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

> see the use of [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) .
>
> The `box-sizing` CSS property sets how the total width and height of an element is calculated.

Comment: thank you very much for sharing the solution, I imagined that the margin was part of the calculation of the border-box.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding 20px to the margin.

change your css for this element:

PREVIOUS:

```
.container_calculator > input {
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px 20px;
}
```

NEW:

```
.container_calculator input {
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just insert `padding` to parent and remove `margin` in input and label.

```
.container_calculator {

   padding: 5px 20px;<-------------insert this line

   //Other codes...

}

.container_calculator > input {

  margin: 5px 20px;<--------------remove this

  //Other codes...

}

.container_calculator>label {

 margin: 10px 0 0 20px;<---------remove this

 //Other codes...

}
```

For space between `input` and `label`,you can use of :

```
.container_calculator>input{

    margin-top:5px;

   //Other codes...

}
```

```css
  html {
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        
        *,
        *::before,
        *::after {
            -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
            -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
            box-sizing: inherit;
        }
        
        body,
        pre {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        .container {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 980px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        
        .container_calculator {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 400px;
            background-color: tomato;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin: 5px auto;
            padding: 5px 20px;
        }
        
        .container_calculator>label {
            display: inline-block;
            color: #fff;
        }
        
        .container_calculator>input {
            height: 20px;
            border: 1px solid tomato;
            border-radius: 5px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        div.result_bin2dec {
            border: 1px solid #edf2f7;
            background-color: #edf2f7;
            border-radius: 10px;
            margin-top: 30px;
            height: 35px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="container_calculator">
                <label>Number</label>
                <input type="text" id="number">
            </div>

            <div class="result_bin2dec">
                <pre>
                        Dec: 10
                        Bin: 01
                    </pre>
            </div>
        </div>
```